# PHP Get Site URL Protocol - http vs https

Tags: php, url, ssl

I've written a little function to establish the current site url protocol but I don't have SSL and don't know how to test if it works under https. **Can you tell me if this is correct?**

```
function siteURL()
{
    $protocol = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off' || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? "https://" : "http://";
    $domainName = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/';
    return $protocol.$domainName;
}
define( 'SITE_URL', siteURL() );
```

**Is it necessary to do it like above or can I just do it like?:**

```
function siteURL()
{
    $protocol = 'http://';
    $domainName = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/'
    return $protocol.$domainName;
}
define( 'SITE_URL', siteURL() );
```

Under SSL, doesn't the server automatically convert the url to https even if the anchor tag url is using http? Is it necessary to check for the protocol?

Thank you!

Comment: Wouldn't it be a better option for you to install a local web server and throw a self signed SSL certificate on it? That way  you can test it for yourself.

Comment: Yes, that would be awesome, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: While this doesn't answer your question, a better solution to your problem (though I can't be sure without knowing more) might be to use [Protocol Relative URLs](http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/).

Comment: Just a quick question...how come you're doing a function if it's not dynamic. It's not like you feed it any vars to change the url. Why not define a constant? That's what I did.

$protocol = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off' || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? "https://" : "http://";
define('SITE_URL', $protocol.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/');

Comment: May I suggest this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php

Answer (score 75, accepted):

It is not automatic.  Your top function looks ok.

Comment: worth noting that it IS automatic if you just leave off the protocol.. ie `//mysqite.com` instead of `https://mysitecom`

Comment: @Pamblam, // works great unless your link is in an email :)

Comment: Or in an xhr request

Answer (score 105):

This works for me

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) &&
    ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 1) ||
    isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) &&
    $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https') {
  $protocol = 'https://';
}
else {
  $protocol = 'http://';
}
```

Comment: This is the solution that works if using a proxy (like in my case CloudFlare)

Comment: This is correct - you shouldn't assume https just because you're using port 443.

Comment: This work fine with normal links as well as with CDN, thanks

Comment: Would it be of benefit to apply the PHP strtolower() Function to the portion of the above code ($_SERVER['HTTPS'])== 'on') so that it read strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']) == 'on' and therefore allowing for instances where the value returned from $_SERVER['HTTPS'] is On or ON?

Answer (score 91):

I know it's late, although there is a much more convenient way to solve this kind of problem! The other solutions are quite messy; this is how I would do it:

```
$protocol = stripos($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'],'https') === 0 ? 'https://' : 'http://';
```

...or even without condition if you prefer:

```
$protocol = strtolower(substr($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"],0,strpos( $_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"],'/'))).'://';
```

**Have a look at [`$_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)**

Comment: This dont work with "https" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16825243/why-is-phps-server-protocol-showing-http-1-1-even-when-using-https

Comment: @wormhit it mainly depends on how your webserver is configured though

Comment: Any reason why you use `stripos` instead of `strpos`?

Comment: @Fred it's just to prevent webserver configuration flaws! in most cases though going `strpos` is absolutely fine `strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'],'HTTPS')`

Comment: Note that `stripos` is slower than `strpos`. I am not aware of any configuration where it might say 'https' in lowercase.

Comment: I did find one - once, and that's the reason why i went that way! If you really want to dig into performance however `isset($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'][4]) && 'S' === $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'][4]` might be even faster than `strpos`. To me it just depends on how many times you need to execute the procedure; I might edit the answer adding a hi-performance version ;)

Comment: `$_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']` is made to store `HTTP/1.0` or `HTTP/1.1` depending on the protocol version, what sort of HTTP server configuration do you talk about, storing `https` information on this string coming from the http query?

Comment: @ejectamenta - Checking if $_SERVER['HTTPS'] is set is insufficient. According to http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php, there's a case where it will be set to 'off'.

I'm down voting the answer as incorrect.

Comment: " Note that when using ISAPI with IIS, the value will be off if the request was not made through the HTTPS protocol" so it doesn't work for Windows servers, but if you are using a UNIX server then it is sufficient

Comment: Or even shorter: `$protocol = strtolower(strstr($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'], '/', TRUE))`

Comment: Doesn't work in my case! $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] contains "HTTP" (without any "S") while the protocol is https. Checking $_SERVER['HTTPS'] is more appropriate.

Comment: This answer is outdated, now that SERVER_PROTOCOL can be     [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/2.0. More robust option is in answer from Rid Iculous (which is, BTW, a ridiculous username ;-)

Answer (score 29):

short way

```
$scheme = $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'] . '://';
```

Comment: `REQUEST_SCHEME` is not reliable

Comment: REQUEST_SCHEME is not available until Apache 2.4.

Answer (score 28):

Some changes:

```
function siteURL() {
  $protocol = ((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off') || 
    $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? "https://" : "http://";
  $domainName = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
  return $protocol.$domainName;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Because testing port number is not a good practice according to me, my solution is:

```
define('HTTPS', isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && filter_var($_SERVER['HTTPS'], FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN));
```

The `HTTPS`constant returns `TRUE` if `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` is set and equals to "1", "true", "on" or "yes".
Returns FALSE otherwise.

Comment: This is probably the best answer. Lots of these answers will will only in a percentage of situations. For example, people are just checking if $_SERVER['HTTPS'] is set. Many frameworks set this variable as false or 'off' etc, therefore checking if it's simply set will not work.

Comment: While this works under most situations, there have been times where there was a configuration SNAFU and $_SERVER['HTTPS'] was actually set to "off". Your code would still regard that as "passing" the test, so should be amended to allow for that particular setting.

Answer (score 7):

For any system except IIS this is quite enough to define site self URL:

```
$siteURL='http'.(empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])?'':'s').'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/';
```

or

```
$siteURL='http'.(empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])?'':'s').'://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/';
```

depends on what you exactly want:
[HTTP_HOST vs. SERVER_NAME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297403/http-host-vs-server-name)

Answer (score 6):

Extracted from CodeIgniter :

```
if ( ! function_exists('is_https'))
{
    /**
     * Is HTTPS?
     *
     * Determines if the application is accessed via an encrypted
     * (HTTPS) connection.
     *
     * @return  bool
     */
    function is_https()
    {
        if ( ! empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']) !== 'off')
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
        elseif (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) === 'https')
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
        elseif ( ! empty($_SERVER['HTTP_FRONT_END_HTTPS']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_FRONT_END_HTTPS']) !== 'off')
        {
            return TRUE;
        }

        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: no link to the source.. let me reference at least [this](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/ae7b30f9cbaf462a3cc039de6d1e7738c6bea2d4/system/core/Common.php#L348)

Answer (score 5):

Use this server variable to get the protocol details:

```
 $scheme = $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'] . '://';
 echo $scheme; //it gives http:// or https://
```

Note that this server variable is unreliable. For more information take a look at:
[Is $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'] reliable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18008135/is-serverrequest-scheme-reliable)

Comment: Can you add some more information to your post, and not only the code? For example explain why this is an answer to the question?

Answer (score 5):

In case of proxy the `SERVER_PORT` may not give the correct value so this is what worked for me -

```
$protocol = ((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off') || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 || $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT'] == 443) ? "https://" : "http://"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$protocal = 'http';
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https' || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') {$protocal = 'https';}


echo $protocal;
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question but I came across this today since I needed to test for this in my site.  It seems the answers above are needlessly complicated.  To establish the site protocol, all you have to do is test `$_SERVER['HTTPS']`

If the protocol is using HTTPS, then `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` will return 'on'.  If not, the variable will remain empty.
For example:

> test if HTTPS is being used.  If it is, the echo will return
> '$SSL_test: on'.  If not HTTPS, '$SSL_test' will remain empty.

```
$SSL_test = $_SERVER['HTTPS'];

echo '<p>$SSL_test: '.$SSL_test.'</p>';
    
if($SSL_test == true) {
    echo 'You\'re using SSL';
} else {
    echo 'You\'re not using SSL';
}
```

You can use the above to easily and cleanly test for HTTPS and implement accordingly.    :)

Comment: Not every server has this $_SERVER['HTTPS']

Answer (score 2):

made a function using the *Rid Iculous*'s answer which worked on my system.

```
function site_protocol() {
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 1) || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) &&  $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https')  return $protocol = 'https://'; else return $protocol = 'http://';
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

I've tested the [most voted answe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15101409/797495)r and it **didn't work for me**, I ended up using:

```
$protocol = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https://' : 'http://';
```

Comment: Some web servers do not support `$_SERVER["HTTPS"]` and therefore your code may return `http://` even if it should be `https://`

Comment: If the server doesn't support, `https`, why would the code still return `https`?

Comment: My server supports https but the `$_SERVER["HTTPS"]` variable is never defined.

Comment: I'm confused by your 2 comments. It's probably better if you create a new answer that covers those special cases. Thanks and good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I do it ... it is a **shorthand** `if else` version of *Rid Iculous's* answer ...

```
$protocol = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 1) || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] === 'https' ? 'https' : 'http';
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the complete func should look like :

```
function siteURL()
{
    $protocol =  "http://";
    if (
        //straight
        isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && in_array($_SERVER['HTTPS'], ['on', 1])
        ||
        //proxy forwarding
        isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https'
    ) {
        $protocol = 'https://';
    }

    $domainName = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    return $protocol . $domainName;
}
```

Notes:

- you should look also for HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO (e.g. if proxy
  server)
- relying on 443 port is not safe (https could be served on
  different port)
- REQUEST_SCHEME not reliable

Answer (score 1):

Also late to the party, but here is a much shorter version of *Rid Iculous's* answer using the **Null Coalescing Operator**:

```
$is_ssl = in_array($_SERVER['HTTPS'] ?? '', ['on', 1]) ||
          ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] ?? '') == 'https';
$protocol = $is_ssl ? 'https://' : 'http://';
```

Or:

```
$protocol = in_array($_SERVER['HTTPS'] ?? '', ['on', 1]) ||
            ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] ?? '') == 'https' ?
            'https://' : 'http://';
```

Answer (score 0):

it's the best solution of https or http use this :

```html
<?php
$protocol = '//';  
$site_url = $protocol.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
?>
```

But can't display https or http, so it only use to link your site content like image, etc.

if want to redirect your site in https, add this code in .htaccess file :

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"http"'
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.your-domain.com$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Change **www.your-domain.com** with your dowmain name.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late to this party, but if you much prefer not using $_SERVER as it's strongly discouraged, and even deactivated on some PHP frameworks; ***and*** you have an apache web server, you can use it's native command thusly: -

```
$protocol = apache_getenv('HTTPS') ? 'https:' : 'http:';
```