# Why is PHP's "SERVER_PROTOCOL" showing HTTP/1.1 even when using https?

Tags: php, https

The addressbar shows "https://mywebsite.com" and it shows a lock icon (and clicking on that shows it's AES-256), but when I run the following code, it always prints "HTTP/1.1".

```
echo $_SERVER[ "SERVER_PROTOCOL" ];
```

Why doesn't this show https?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

SERVER_PROTOCOL has nothing to do with the security of your page, it reports if the connections used are HTTP 1.0 or HTTP 1.1 or HTTP 2.0:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol

> HTTP/1.1 is a revision of the original HTTP (HTTP/1.0). In HTTP/1.0 a
>   separate connection to the same server is made for every resource
>   request. HTTP/1.1 can reuse a connection multiple times to download
>   images, scripts, stylesheets et cetera after the page has been
>   delivered. HTTP/1.1 communications therefore experience less latency
>   as the establishment of TCP connections presents considerable
>   overhead.

While HTTP 2.0 is the next generation of HTTP that allows multiplexing of multiple HTTP 1.1 connections inside one HTTP 2.0 connection.

For your purposes, check if the HTTPS server variable is set:

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

i.e. something like

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') { ... }
```

Comment: Warning: `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` could be set but contain the string `off`.

Comment: This won't work for cronjobs / CLI scripts, though.