# Setting the SERVER_PROTOCOL to HTTP/1.1 in centOS

Tags: http, http-protocols

I want to set the http SERVER_PROTOCOL as HTTP/1.1 in my CentOS system. The system is currently configured with Apache/2.2.15 and PHP/5.4.10. But the PHP info file in my server shows as:

```
SERVER_PROTOCOL     HTTP/1.0
```

How to change it to:

```
SERVER_PROTOCOL     HTTP/1.1
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16825243/why-is-phps-server-protocol-showing-http-1-1-even-when-using-https

Comment: it says about viewing the protocol only, but how to change it

Comment: Do you access that information by a HTTP/1.1 request?

Comment: how to make a HTTP/1.1 request? I just have called the 'phpinfo' function for viewing the details which shows as HTTP/1.0.