# Adding base_url() to header

Tags: php

Is it possible to have something like the following but which actually works?

```
header('location: base_url(). page.php?x=3');
```

Comment: If you're trying to build the a `base_url()` function, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17201261/1438393) should get you started. The code in your question isn't working because you can't call functions inside single-quotes. Use concatenation as shown in @hsz's answer.

Comment: @AmalMurali, I think OP is using the `base_url()` of the CI framework.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran: I'm aware of the function, but I wasn't sure if the OP was using CI (as the question wasn't tagged so).

Comment: @Christian How do you know that the OP uses CI framework? Please don't add tags unless it's obvious that the question is related to that specific tag.

Answer (score 8):

Try with:

```
header('Location: ' . base_url() . '/page.php?x=3');
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this for delayed redirect in header:

```
header('Refresh:5; url= '. base_url().'/YOURcontrollerName_or_functionName');
```