# How to get domain name with PHP

Tags: php, parsing, url, dns

I know (and see) that this question has been asked for about a thousand times, but, after search and search, and somewhat confusing answers, i'm still looking for a right answer.

All I need is to identify my domain from url like (http://www.example.com; or http://example.com or www.example.com or just example.com) (no subdomains-for now) with PHP.

I'm creating a simple website, but hosted on 2 seperate domains (with same contents), and i need to identify on which site (domain) user is, in order to display the right logo, disclaimer etc.

Thanks.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459739/php-serverhttp-host-vs-serverserver-name-am-i-understanding-the-ma

Comment: just try some of the thousand examples you have and see what happens. I'm 100% sure one of them gets you there

Comment: tried, tried, tried, nothing seem to work, whatever i do it renders me the entire link, all in need is to separete 2 domain extensions (.com and .net - same domain name) simple IF loop. please help

Comment: Are you saying you want to extract and use the domain extension, rather than the whole domain?  See my expanded answer below where I do an if on the full name, and then find the extension utilising a reverse strpos (strrpos) to locate the full stop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP how to get the base domain/url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17201170/php-how-to-get-the-base-domain-url)

Answer (score 1):

for getting server name: $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']
for reference: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php