# Customised link text with php

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a text like

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">www.google.com</a>
```

I want to show this text as `www.google.com` with click able option and
 this should open in in new tab. I have used strip_tags, but it only
 displays the content without click able option.

Below is **my code**:

```
 {{ strip_tags(nl2br($user->content)) }}
```

How can I do this in `laravel`?

Comment: the text is <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">www.google.com</a>

Comment: Edit the url in controller, and show it in view

Comment: `<a href="{{ $url }}" target="_blank">{{ $url }}</a>`

Comment: how can I clean that text in the controller?

Comment: Look here how to clean url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17201170/php-how-to-get-the-base-domain-url

Comment: how are you loading the view?

Comment: which version of laravel are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to output it, strip_tags actualy strips HTML tags off. Just do {{ $user->content }}  and you should have the desired output.

Comment: Can you include example with the blade html? Something like my comment in the question

Comment: I already gave you, it's literally just {{ $user->content }} based, of course, on what you said, that the value of $user->content is the HTML of anchor, you are rendering a template, so you just need to output it's value.