# Display image<img src=""> from the database path to PHP webpage

Tags: image-loading

I would like to display/load image from the database, my image path is stored in database. My project file is in different drive (d:) and my images are in share drive (Z:). Currently I am working on localhost. When I inspect my webpage,  shows my path, but it give error in console as "Not allowed to load local resource:".

below is my code:

```
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
 $imageURL =  $row['Bildpfad'];
                        
                        $color = ($row['ErgebnisOrig'] == "0") ? "#43D934" : ($row['ErgebnisOrig'] == "1" ? "#F36565" : 
                                        ($row['ErgebnisOrig'] == "2" ? "#F3CE32" : "#6E6E6E"));  // check for nIO IO NA
                        $erg = ($row['ErgebnisOrig'] == "0") ? "IO" : ($row['ErgebnisOrig'] == "1" ? "nIO" : 
                                        ($row['ErgebnisOrig'] == "2" ? "NA" : "nres"));  // display text of IO nIO NA and nres 
                        // Generate HTML for each image
                        echo "<div class='outer_block$counter'><div class = 'st_$counter'>".$condition['MessStation']."</div>
                        <div class='st_$counter'></div>
                        <div class='s_$counter'></div>
                        <div class='erg_$counter' style='background-color:".$color."'>$erg</div>
                        <div class='dt_$counter'>$datePart</div>
                        <div class='time_$counter'>$timePart</div>
                        <div class='inner_block$counter'><img src='$imageURL' class='img$counter' onclick='redirectToLayerPage()'></div>
                        </div>";
                        $counter++;
                    }
                }
```

Please suggest me how to display/load local images/share drive images to webpage in PHP

Comment: What is the rendered value for `$imageURL`?

Comment: it's my imagepath in database. 
Z:\***\**\3830690902100\20231110_185010\20231110_185010_cam0_pose000.png

Comment: You should not save the whole path to the image in your DB. If the images are uploaded in one specific folder just save the images filename and add a relative path to the image in your loop. Like `$imageURL = '/path/to/images/' . $row['Bildpfad'];` The relative path should be stored in a variable as well of course (config file?). You can build a absolute path including your domain as well of course!

Comment: I am adding multiple image on one webpage from this path.  How to write relative path? and absolute path? 
I am working on localhost http://localhost:3000/detail_data.php
my image path Z:\PROVIM_Pics\job7011737448\3830690902100\20231110_185010\20231110_185010_cam0_pose000.png

Also my working directory is different, not in Z:. Z: is a share drive.

Comment: You uploaded images have to be saved inside your PHP website so you can reach them by i.e. `localhost:3000/uploads/images/20231110_185010_cam0_pose000.png`. Here you find some inspiration how to get the domain base: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17201170/php-how-to-get-the-base-domain-url

Comment: If I add images into my project folder, I can load them, but I want it from Z: only.