# Enabling http and https PHP

Tags: php, http, pdf, https

I have a PDF converter button that works fine for http requests.

```
$this->url ='http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].':'.$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'].str_replace(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR , $relativePath , '/' );
```

However I need to make it work for a https request as well.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have issues fetching the protocol from what i can see. Check this question: [PHP Get Site URL Protocol - http vs https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503135/php-get-site-url-protocol-http-vs-https)