# Tumblr share button not working with PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am trying to implment the share button on my website, but it does not work when I use php. However it does work when I input the data manunaly.

for example this works:

```
<a href="http://www.tumblr.com/share/link?url=https%3A%2F%2Fdomain.com&amp;name=test&amp;description=test">Share on Tumblr</a>
```

but this does not:

```
<a href="http://www.tumblr.com/share/link?url=<?=urlencode(current_url())?>&amp;name=test&amp;description=test">Share on Tumblr</a>
```

When I click on the one using PHP I get redirected to:

```
https://www.tumblr.com/widgets/share/tool/banned?
```

EDIT: I even tried doing it this way:

```
var tumblr_link_url = '<?=current_url()?>';
var tumblr_link_name = 'test';
var tumblr_link_description = 'test';
var url = "http://www.tumblr.com/share/link?url=" + encodeURIComponent(tumblr_link_url) + "&amp;name=" + encodeURIComponent(tumblr_link_name) + "&amp;description=" + encodeURIComponent(tumblr_link_description);
var tumblr_button = document.createElement("a");
tumblr_button.setAttribute("href", url);
tumblr_button.setAttribute("title", "Share on Tumblr");
tumblr_button.innerHTML = "Share on Tumblr";
document.getElementById("tumblr_button").appendChild(tumblr_button);
```

but it still does not work. It definitely has something to do with using PHP. My other share buttons work, it's only the Tumblr share button that has this problem when using PHP

Any reason why this does not work?

Comment: what's the rendered output in the html source?

Comment: this is how the one using PHP renders in the browser: `http://www.tumblr.com/share/link?url=http%3A%2F%2Fdomain%2Fimage%2F98&name=test&description=test`

Comment: why is it that in your working example, your url is for `share/photo?` but the non-working one is for `share/link?`?

Comment: That is a mistake. I will correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tumblr forbids you to post invalid urls such as `domain`, which I assume you've obfuscated for this forum. in your working example, you actually use `domain.com` as an example, which is in fact a real site which is why it works on tumblr. **notice the absence of the `.com` in your broken example.**

> **side note:** unless you're trying to advertise for [domain.com](http://www.domain.com/), I would encourage you to use a non-commercial entity like [`example.com`](http://example.com/)

I may be wrong, but I'm guessing that you're testing this on a local development machine whose current url would be `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`, or an otherwise firewall protected host, which are also invalid URLs to tumblr because they are not world accessible. Your code *should* work just fine on a world accessible server.

It's also worth noting in my tests - which I'm no code igniter fan, so perhaps I skipped a configuration setting - that the `current_url()` function returns my IP, and not the hostname. This actually isn't a problem, because tumblr will accept a valid accessible IP address also, but it may be undesirable. So if you're experiencing this, I simply rebuilt the whole URL following [this guide](http://www.phpf1.com/tutorial/get-current-page-url.html) with a little help from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503135/php-get-site-url-protocol-http-vs-https#4503213) to get the protocol right as such:

```
<?php 
$protocol = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off' || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? "https" : "http";
$host     = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$script   = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
$params   = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$currentUrl = $protocol . '://' . $host . $script . '?' . $params;
?>
<a href="http://www.tumblr.com/share/link?url=<?=urlencode($currentUrl)?>&amp;name=test&amp;description=test">Share on Tumblr</a>
```

You can see the working example [here](http://jeffpuckett.com/codeigntest/), notice the small "share on tumblr" link at the bottom. The full source code for that is [here](https://github.com/admonkey/codeignitertest/blob/master/application/views/welcome_message.php).

Comment: Thanks. The `current_url()` returns the current page url for me. after seeing your answer and some more research I think it comes down to it not working in local development. I will try in production when I'm ready.