# file name listing from directory including folders and subfolders

Tags: php

i want to list out all files in a directory `wallpaper/`. there are more than 1000 folders inside this directory which are mainly celebrity name like angelina joulie etc and inside that folder several images are there for that celebrity.

i want to list all files with total path 
like `http://xyz.com/wallpaper/angelina joulie/angeli1243.jpg`

i tried `scandir()` `readdir()` `glob()` but all lists only current directory.

please tell how to list all files full path including subdirectory of a given directory

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240462/php-convert-file-system-path-to-url

Comment: But have you tried `glob("wallpaper/*/*")`?

Comment: @jack no i have tried one star

Comment: All you need is [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/recursivedirectoryiterator.construct.php)

Comment: @raviloves that's good to hear, want me to put it up as an answer?

Comment: @Jack sure it was exatly what i was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need to go two levels in, it would be far easier to use `glob()`:

```
glob("wallpaper/*/*")
```

Will traverse all immediate directories underneath `wallpaper/`.

Comment: i am trying to upload data to mysql table but whereever any gap is not there and all lines are in new line it does the work but whereever lines are like this www.xyz.com/xyzk/dhdjje ejjj.jpg it breaks and stores words into databse any new tutorial can u please suggest to import data

Answer (score 0):

You need a recursive function. Here is a sample function that's tested and working properly.

```
function recursiveReaddir($folderPath = '.')
{
    $ignore = array('cgi-bin', '.', '..');
    $handle = @opendir($folderPath);
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {

        if (!in_array($file, $ignore)) {
            if (is_dir("$folderPath/$file")) {
                $return[$file] = recursiveReaddir("$folderPath/$file");
            } else {
                $return [] = $file;
            }
        }
    }

    closedir($handle);
    return $return;
}
$rez = recursiveReaddir('path/to/file');
print_r($rez);
```

Comment: yes, it returns an array, you can do whatever you want with it

Comment: @vlap-preda nothing is coming i checked

Comment: @vlap-preda i want to list like links can u please tell how to do like http://xyz.com/wallpaper/angelina joulie/angeli1243.jpg

Comment: if you're not on your own server to access files/folder with relative paths, you may not be able to do that (depending on server restrictions)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23759/discussion-between-raviloves-and-vlad-preda)