# PHP: Systems path to actual URL

Tags: php

Before i make my question I wanna say that I have tried every related post I found from stackoverflow such as [PHP - Convert File system path to URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240462/php-convert-file-system-path-to-url)  and nothing worked for me, meaning I did not get the Url I was looking for.

I need a

```
function PathToUrl($path) 
{
 ... 
}
```

which returns the actual Url of the `$path`

**Example usage:** `echo PathToUrl('../songs');` should output `http://www.mywebsite.com/files/morefiles/songs`.

**Note:** The problem with the functions i found on stackoverflow is that they dont work with path that contains `../`  for example on  `echo PathToUrl('../songs');` i would get something similar to `http://www.mywebsite.com/files/morefiles/../songs` which is not what i am looking for.

Comment: From my experience, you need to use a combination of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` with realpath(__FILE__)  to determine the location of that file in combination with where the path reflects on the address bar.  In your case, the answer could be as simple as explode() on the / , and then remove from the end of the array as many items you wish to ../ to, then implode().

Comment: It doesn't work that way from what i have seen... its more complicated

Comment: yes thats the problem , the `../` , i was thinking someone has already implemented a similar function, because creating something like this from zero would take a lot of effort and time , its pretty hard actually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, I made this function and it works perfectly:

```
function getPath($path)
{
    $url = "http".(!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])?"s":"").
        "://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $dirs = explode('/', trim(preg_replace('/\/+/', '/', $path), '/'));
    foreach ($dirs as $key => $value)
        if (empty($value))  unset($dirs[$key]);
    $parsedUrl = parse_url($url);
    $pathUrl = explode('/', trim($parsedUrl['path'], '/'));
    foreach ($pathUrl as $key => $value)
        if (empty($value))  unset($pathUrl[$key]);
    $count = count($pathUrl);
    foreach ($dirs as $key => $dir)
        if ($dir === '..')
            if ($count > 0)
                array_pop($pathUrl);
            else
                throw new Exception('Wrong Path');
        else if ($dir !== '.')
            if (preg_match('/^(\w|\d|\.| |_|-)+$/', $dir)) {
                $pathUrl[] = $dir;
                ++$count;
            }
            else
                throw new Exception('Not Allowed Char');
    return $parsedUrl['scheme'].'://'.$parsedUrl['host'].'/'.implode('/', $pathUrl);
}
```

---

**Example**:

Let's say your current location is `http://www.mywebsite.com/files/morefiles/movies`,

---

```
echo getPath('../songs');
```

**OUTPUT**

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/files/morefiles/songs
```

---

```
echo getPath('./songs/whatever');
```

**OUTPUT**

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/files/morefiles/movies/songs/whatever
```

---

```
echo getPath('../../../../../../');
```

In this case it will throw an **[exception](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)**.

---

**NOTE**

I use this regex `'/^(\w|\d|\.| |_|-)+$/'` to check the path directories which mean that only digit, word characters, '.', '-', '_' and ' ' are allowed. An exception will be trown for others characters.

The path `.///path` will be corrected by this function.

**USEFUL**

- **[explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)**
- **[implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)**
- **[array_pop](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php)**
- **[parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)**
- **[trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)**
- **[preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)**
- **[preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)**

Comment: um , atually, it doesnt work with `../` :S `echo getPath('../song');`  gave me `http://www.mywebsite.com/files/morefiles/movies/song`

Comment: ok , i am holding on to that , because i get an `Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Not Allowed Char' `

Comment: @Shiro I edited my function, it should work. By the way I made this exception. It means you passed a string with a character not allowed like `../song<`

Comment: i dont know why but i get `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Not Allowed Char' in /home4/shiro/public_html/scr/add/index.php:199 Stack trace: #0 /home4/shiro/public_html/scr/add/index.php(234): PathToUrl('../mp3s/U-Recke...') #1 /home4/shiro/public_html/scr/add/index.php(258): ShowDirectories() #2 {main} thrown in /home4/shiro/public_html/scr/add/index.php on line 199`

Comment: What did you pass to the function ?

Comment: I passed this `../mp3s` , before it worked but it didnt count the `../` it was as if i inputed `/mp3s`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62051/discussion-between-adam-sinclair-and-shiro).

Answer (score 1):

I see an answer was already posted, however I will post my solution which allows for direct specification of the URL :

```
echo up('http://www.google.ca/mypage/losethisfolder/',1);

function up($url, $howmany=1) {
    $p = explode('/', rtrim($url, '/'));
    if($howmany < count($p)) {
        $popoff = 0;
        while($popoff < $howmany) {
            array_pop($p);
            $popoff++;
        }
    }
    return rtrim(implode('/', $p), '/') . '/';
}
```

Following is a much more elegant solution for virtual paths :

```
$path = '/foo/../../bar/../something/../results/in/skipthis/../this/';

echo virtualpath($path);

function virtualpath($path = null) {
    $loopcount = 0;
    $vpath = $path;
    if(is_null($vpath)) { $vpath = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH); }
    $vpath = rtrim($vpath,'/') . '/';
    while(strpos($vpath,'../') !== false ) {
        if(substr($vpath,0,4) == '/../') { $vpath = '/'. substr($vpath,4); }
        $vpath = preg_replace('/(\/[\w\d\s\ \-\.]+?\/\.\.\/)/', '/', $vpath );
    }
    return $vpath;
}
```